# Issue with accessing local server with IP address

Tags: windows, windows-7, web-server, ip, websphere

Folks, I am stuck with a weird problem here. I am running a Websphere server locally on my Win 7 machine. Http port is 9081. When I am trying to access my application using localhost it works fine, as soon as I replace it with my IP address it stops responding.
Is this a Win 7 quirk? How to fix it?

Works: `http://localhost:9081/myApp/first.html`

Doesn't work: `http://<XX.XX.XX.XX>:9081/myApp/first.html`

Where XX.XX.XX.XX is my local IP Address. I have confirmed my IP address again n again with `ipconfig`

Comment: How does "doesn't work" look? No response or error message? Immediately or after some delay?

Answer (score 1):

Your Websphere server could be listening only on the loopback interface. Confirm this using netstat

```
netstat -an | findstr "9081"
```

If you see a response like this:

```
 127.0.0.1:9081
```

You might need to configure your service to listen on the other interfaces connected to the network.

Answer (score 0):

My 1st guess would be some sort of antivirus/firewall software that may possibly shutting down ports.

You might want to verify that by trying to telnet to port 9081 from another machine to your Win7 machine to ensure that it connects.